# Передача большого объема данных спомощью веб сервиса

Tags: c#

Нужно передать **1 Гб** с помощью *веб сервиса*. Думаю передавать кусочно использую **msmq**. Может есть способ полегче?

Comment: м, может их просто в файл записать и по сети обычным http передать?

Comment: Мне кажется, на `server-side` для этого подойдет любое решение, которое может стримить файлы `chunk by chunk.` См. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/608480/best-way-to-stream-files-in-asp-net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А чем плох метод, когда вы реализуете веб метод который будет принемать скажем имя файла, offset, block_length, binary data скажем на 16кб, А клинет будет засылать или получать, сам решая какой именно кусок ему нужен?